# How can I cache a String with firebase? (android)

Tags: android, firebase, caching

I want to cache the Username of the current user logged in, because I don't want to reload the username string everytime the activity refreshes.

What methods/startegies can I use to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of solutions to fix your issue :

- you can save the user name into sharedpref or into database
- As an advanced solution i would like to advice you to read about the Singleton design patter : the idea is to create a class and to make a public one Single instance from it (you can do when the user login) and then every class in your project can get access to it. [please take a look here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-design-patterns-the-singleton-pattern--cms-29153)

**Concerning the easiest way to solve your issue i believe that shared preferences can do the job**

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("name", "abc");
 editor.commit();
```

**And to retrieve your data you can proceed like following :**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
if (restoredText != null) {
  String name = prefs.getString("name", "No name defined");//"No name defined" is the default value.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As one of the tag in question is marked "Firebase", I will assume you are using Firebase as your back-end and Firebase Auth for authenticating the user.

Firebase allows you to get the Display Name, Email-id (username) and users profile picture using "FirebaseUser".

To retrieve the user associated information use the below code:

```
      FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
      FirebaseAuth user_token = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
      FirebaseUser currentUser = user_token.getCurrentUser();

      currentUser.getDisplayName(); //Display Name
      currentUser.getEmail(); //Username
      currentUser.getPhotoUrl(); //PhotoURL if the user used any social media for auth
```